# Javascript framework for simple webapp

Tags: javascript, web-applications

i need develop simple webapp for devices with poor internet-connection speed. This webapp should get json string from server (jsonrpc\restfull web-service) and render it on client. In other words it should be something like:

> — on url **/list** load file **list.htm** and perform **list.js** on it
>
> — on url **/about** load file **about.htm** and perform **about.js** on it

On some pages i should open `WebSocket` connection and i need close this connection when user goes to another page. So, i need basically lifecycle events. Also it will be great if i can use transition animation between urls.

### Backbone.js

First of all i check `backbone.js`. Great low-level tool with big community. But it is very very low-level, there is no such lifecycle events for views. Also there is difficult-to-understand logic.

### Ember.js

Good tool, but i am stuck with some misunderstood to documentation. It seems developers write code faster, then documentation, so many parts of documentation isn't usable at all.

### Angular.js

I thinks this is greatest tool from all what i see! Great MVC logic, but also problem with docs. Stacked with this problem: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1830

========

Now i am really tired with choose toolkit for my needs. All fw looks too complicated for this task. Maybe i seek in wrong place? Today i look to `jQueryMobile` framework. It looks like what i need (with page preloaders, page-change animations). But it targeted for developing mobile-apps with mobile UI.

Maybe i miss something? What fw should i also see? Or should i use backbone\ember\angular? Is there some examples which can i check. All examples just show how model bind to view and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single right answer to your question. I would recommend looking at the [ToDoMVC project](http://todomvc.com/) which presents the same application implemented with a range of JavaScript frameworks.

You should also read

[Journey through the JavaScript MVC Jungle.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/)